# Bootstrap social icons goes down a line on chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm using this code to show social icons and it works well on Firefox and IE, but not on Chrome. on chrome both icons are going down one line while on the other browsers they stay in the same line together with the nav-brand. What might be the problem?

```
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">DailyMeal
                </a>

                <a href="https://instagram.com/dailyyummymeals/">
                    <i title="Follow us on Instagram" class="fa fa-instagram"
                    style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:20px;"></i>
                </a>

                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dailymeal.co">
                    <i title="Follow us on Facebook" class="fa fa-facebook"
                    style="cursor:pointer;padding-top:20px;"></i>
                </a>
```

Comment: Please provide a `JSFiddle` or your HTML/CSS code for your query.

Comment: Solved it, had to wrap it up with a div for some reason.